# Как запретить постоянную ajax подгрузку?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

У меня возникла ошибка

При прокрутке до нужного места подгружаю часть сайта, но подгрузка постоянно происходит.

Как запретить постоянную ajax подгрузку?

Вот сам код

```
 <script>  
    var limit = 0; 
    var start = 0;   
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var action = 'inactive'; 
        function load_country_data(){
        $.ajax({
           url:'test.php',
           method:"POST",
           data:{limit:limit, start:start},
           cache:false,
           success:function(data){
              $('#load_data').append(data);
              if(data == ''){
                  $('#load_data_message').html("<button type='button' class='btn btn-info'>No Data Found</button>");
                  action = 'active';
              } else {
                  $('#load_data_message').html("<button type='button' class='btn btn-warning'>Please Wait....</button>");
                  action = 'inactive';
              }

            }
          });
       }
       $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $("#load_data").height() && action == 'inactive')
        {
            action = 'active';
            start = start + limit;
            setTimeout(function(){
                load_country_data(limit, start);
            }, 1000);
        }
       });
    });
    </script>
```

Вот html

```
<div id="load_data"></div>
<div id="load_data_message"></div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
```

Comment: Кст, а почему в функции `load_country_data` нет параметров? тут они передаются: `load_country_data(limit, start);`, но в саму функцию эти параметры не попадают